# Same array indexes - sequential comparison

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, comparison

I have following problem, kindly help solve this by looping/recursion/function or any other suitable method. The problem is the following:

```
if (($a[0]==$a[1]) && ($a[1]==$a[2])) do operation1
else if(($a[0]==$a[1])&& ($a[1]!==$a[2])) do operation2
```

However, I tried by many approaches, one of them is:

```
for($x=1; $x<$arrlength; $x++)   {   
$a = (strncasecmp($sort[$x],$sort[$x++],strpos($sort[$x],'-')) == 0);

for ($y = 2; $y < $x; $y++)
{
$b = (strncasecmp($a,$sort[$y+1],strpos($a,'-')) == 0);
  switch ($b)
{
case ($b == true)  : 

echo  " <TH class=\"tr1 td26\"><P class=\"p16 ft4\">".substr($sort[$y],0,strpos($sort[$y],'-'))."</P>";

echo "<P class=\"p12 ft4\">".ltrim(substr($sort[$b],strpos($sort[$b],'-')),"-")."</p></TH>";
echo  " <TH class=\"tr1 td26\"><P class=\"p12 ft4\">".ltrim(substr($sort[$y],strpos($sort[$y],'-')),"-")."</P></TH>";
break;

}
}     }
```

This problem is that the solution didn't work and `ltrim` the values properly.

Comment: `switch(4b) { case ($b == true): /*stuff*/ break;`????? best read the docs on `switch`. Really... also: your loops start from 1 and 2 respectively, while an array is, generally zero indexed...

Comment: I dont need the 0 index bro, moreover, 4b is wrong.

Comment: this is not the same question u fool

Comment: Can you please describe what your code does (or doesn't do) in more detail? Writing what it's supposed to do in a list of steps is usually a good way to start. Also, just some friendly advice from someone who's been here for a while, putting time into writing a clear question is often necessary to get the kind of answer you're looking for, and takes a lot of practice. Spending 10 minutes or more to explain a problem makes it much easier for people to figure out what exactly is wrong and provide you with answers. [Read here for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)