# output 2D array in row wise fashion

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, indexing

i have the following output generated by a 2D array, i want to print them hierarchy wise, like first array have value on 2nd index, should be printed above the 2nd index of 2nd array and so on.

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string 'abc' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string 'Mining' (length=6)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string 'Man' (length=3)
      4 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '1969-70=100' (length=11)
      1 => string '1975-76=100' (length=11)
      2 => string '1980-81=100' (length=11)
      3 => string '198081=100' (length=10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I've always done it:

```
<?php

// Assuming the array in your question is named $big_array

echo "<table><tbody>";

foreach($big_array as $small array){
    echo "<tr><td>".implode('</td><td>',$small_array)."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</tbody></table>";
```

[foreach() docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)
[implode() docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

If this doesn't work, try editing your question and making what you're asking for more clear.

Comment: please check the following question, as no 1 answered me .. :(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565011/same-array-indexes-sequential-comparison